# generator-gulp-angular - multiple apps

Tags: angularjs, gulp, yo

I am using [Swiip/generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) and I want to have two separate SPAs(index.html) built into dist folder.

I wish `gulp serve` and `gulp dist:serve` to build those two SPAs, the first will be built into `dist/index.html` and the second will be built into `dist/app2/index.html` assuming that `app2` was defined as another source folder, similar to the `src` folder.

If anyone can guide me on how to modify [Swiip/generator-gulp-angular] or to point me to another gulp solution, it would be great and highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I guess that I can create two sub-directories app1 and app2 that are generated with [Swiip/generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular). Each folder will be configured to dump the destination to a subdirectory in the a dist directory inside the root folder of the project. Then I can create a gulp file with a task to call the build of those two projects separately. I hope that it will work.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I want to complete separate frontend projects, and serve them from same domain using [Heroku to serve static content](https://github.com/adityabansod/static-heroku-node) which make me build and deploy them as one upon git push. I can stop using, Heroku, but I would like to avoid it, as it simplifies git deployment and hosting.

Comment: I can use S3 and deploy the projects separately using [gulp s3 package for deployment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-s3). But then I cannot really support browsers that doesn't support GZIP, [see here](https://www.alfajango.com/blog/how-to-combine-gzip-plus-cdn-for-fastest-page-loads), which is kind of OK but the deployment will not be automatic as connecting Heroku directly to a git branch.

Comment: Normally we use a config file in each servers, and `build` from server itself rather than pushing the build. If you want to create another build just duplicate and rename the `build` task and change the build directory.

Comment: Asim, Thank you for the input. I am not pushing the build, I am pushing the source code. The build is triggered using [heroku build pack](https://github.com/appstack/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-gulp)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding:

You want a gulp task which will **run both build** tasks and **copy one build folder to inner-directory** of other build folder.

So if `buildApp1` and `buildApp2` are the build tasks for app1 and app2 respectively, like this:

```
gulp.task('buildApp1', ['html1', 'fonts1', 'other1']);
gulp.task('buildApp2', ['html2', 'fonts2', 'other2']);
// renamed default build tasks from generator (ref: gulp/build.js)
```

These tasks will create the `dist/` folder in each app directory (you may want to rename the folders, like to `distApp1/` and `distApp2/` in gulp `conf.js` for simplicity).

Then we combine these tasks in default `build`:

```
gulp.task('build', ['buildApp1', 'buildApp2', 'copy']); 
//notice the copy task at the end
```

*Note that we already had two build task we renamed it to buildApp1 and buildApp2*

And here is the copy task which should be written in build.js file

```
// The task for copying buildApp1 to innerdirectory of buildApp2 folder
gulp.task('copy', function(){
  return gulp.src(['distApp1/**/*'], {base:"."})
  .pipe(gulp.dest(' /innerfolder'));
});
// distApp1 and distApp2 are the generated folders.
```

This is just the overview. Still you have to create both build tasks yourself from existing files, Which you can do easily mostly by renaming and tweaking.

Comment: Asim, thank you, It seems that it should work, lemme give it a try. I have two suggestion for improvements: 1. Instead of copy pasting code of html1, html2 and so on... I can create config tasks (configApp1/configApp2) and define the build task as: `gulp.task('build', ['configApp1', 'html', 'fonts', 'other', 'configApp2', 'html', 'fonts', 'other', 'copy']);`. 2. Why do I need the copy? I can configure the dist path of the app2 to be distApp1/innerfolder directly. Do you think that it is a good plan?

Comment: Asim, I implemented with something like this `gulp.task('build', gulpSequence('configApp1', 'html', 'fonts', 'other', 'configApp2', 'html', 'fonts', 'other'));` to avoid parallelism issues, the configuration is tricky but I solved it, there are many dependencies in the server.js that I currently trying to solve.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's good plan. If you solve it, you can edit the answer yourself. Glad to help.

Comment: I just wanted to note that I never got to test any of the solutions because requirements in my project changed and it became irrelevant. Thank you Asim